# Reshaping and applying rotations to the MNIST dataset

Tags: python, image-rotation, mnist

I'm trying to rotate the images in the MNIST dataset (in csv) with the additional goal of recording the angles as labels (instead of the digits 0-9 as labels). I have the following steps in mind:

```
sample_digit = df.iloc[42].values.reshape(28,28) # reshapes 784 => 28x28
rotated = rotate(sample_digit, angle) # rotates the reshaped data by 'angle'
```

And this works for the above image. But what I'm looking to do, and can't seem to be able to, is loop over the df to:
1) reshape each data point to 28x28,
2) apply a random rotation, and
3) record the angle Something like this:

```
rotated_images = []
angles = []
for i, row in df.itertuples():
    reshaped = row.values.reshape(28,28)
    rotated = rotate(sample_digit, angle)
    rotated_images.append(rotated)
    angles.append(angle)
```

Thanks!

Comment: so what is the error you re getting?